# Use get_cat_ID to retreive multiple category IDs

Tags: wp-query, categories, taxonomy

I am trying to use the names of categories stored in user meta (ie users' preferences) to control an on-page query’s parameters.

```
$topicsofinterest = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'topics_of_interest',true);

// returns

array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "Business" [1]=> string(27) "DIY, crafts and houskeeping" [2]=> string(5) "Music" }
```

This needs to be converted in `'8','9','10'` so it can be used in `category__in`

I know I need to use the `get_cat_id` function to lookup the category ID and I have successfully done this using individual category names, eg

```
get_cat_ID (‘Business')

//returns correct category ID as int
```

However, when I try a foreach loop

```
foreach($topicsofinterest as $topicofinterest){
        get_cat_ID($topicsofinterests);
    }
```

`$topicofinterest` returns `string(5) "Music"`

How do I get a clean list of category IDs, ie `'8','9','10'`??

Answer (score 0):

```
$category_in = array();
foreach($topicsofinterest as $topicofinterest){

    //Chaneg 'category' to the taxonomy name.
    $term = get_term_by( 'name', $topicofinterest, 'category');
    
    $category_in[] = $term->term_id;
}
```

Just curious, why don't you store the category ID instead of category name in user meta?

Comment: Huzzah! That works Thank you, sir.

The answer to your question is "because I was a Wordpress coding novice" when someone created those user fields for me. Knowing what I know now, I 100% agree with you!

Comment: @smallnorthumbrianvillage If that worked, can you please mark this as accepted answer

Comment: I tried - unfortunately I don't have the kudos to do so. (Which is a very silly rule.)